# sorting numbers in swift does not give the result

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code for sorting the items ,im running the code online but it does not provide me any kind of result ,below is my code :

```
var numbers = [0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2]
numbers.sort {
    return $0 < $1
}
```

Im a beginner in swift development please correct me if my question is irrelavant.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it doesn't give you a result? How did you test that?

Comment: i got that from google and tried in online compiler but didnt give me any errors

Comment: Add the line println(numbers) after the "}" and see what it prints out.

Comment: Well, doesn't that just mean it works? But you're not trying to _get_ any results, so it won't show you any. Try `println(numbers)` or `map(numbers) { println($0) }`

Comment: Actually i thought that return $0<$1 would give me sorted numbers ,but now i knew it was just to compare.Thank you all for support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numbers = [0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2]
numbers.sort {
    return $0 < $1
}
println(numbers)
```

Thanks [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar),loving swift!

Comment: your answer is correct it included in question only so why are you posted this question man. its not good. and you have not accepted any answer.

Comment: i know you just miss println line. but Amadan already posted answer. so why you post it again and you not accepts Amadan answer.

Comment: i think he want to write print but in hurry he don't remember to write it correct.

Answer (score 4):

`numbers.sort` does not return anything, it modifies `numbers`. How about this?

```
var numbers = [0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2]
numbers.sort {
    return $0 < $1
}
println(numbers)
```

Alternately, you want the non-destructive variant:

```
var numbers = [0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2]
println(sorted(numbers, { $0 < $1 }))
```

EDIT: (As JacobsonTalom rightfully noted, you could also write `numbers.sort()` and `sorted(numbers)`, without the `{ return $0 < $1 }` bit. Also, modified for non-playground usage.)

Comment: giving error : <stdin>:6:1: error: expression resolves to an unused l-value
numbers
^~~~~~~

Comment: @utility This answer is based on how you could output `numbers` when running in a Playground. Since you're using an online compiler, you probably have to use `println(numbers)`.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment.. oh well :)

Comment: @JacobsonTalom: No worries. (He said: `{ $0 < $1 }` is extraneous, as it is the default; and I agree - I just blindly followed the OP's code with minimal changes)

Answer (score 1):

```
let numbers = [0, 2, 3, 5, 10, 2].sorted(<)   // [0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 10]
```